# How to pass Command Parameter of Button

Tags: c#, .net, sql, events, button

I want to pass assignment_id which is a command parameter of myButton to .cs file to update values in database. I wrote this code but when i clicked at myButton it showed a Message Box that Method and Operation is failed. How can i solve this Problem?

```
private void Command(Int32 parameter)
{
    p = parameter;
}

private void btnUpdate_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{  
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local); Integrated Security=true; Database=nrcs");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Assignments SET assignment_title='myassignment'  WHERE assignment_id=" + p + ";", con);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here Xaml Code:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="update" Command="{Binding Command}"     CommandParameter="{Binding assignment_id}" Click="btnUpdate_Click" ></Button>
```

Comment: I suppose you should not use neither the command not command parameters, nor even binding, unless you are writing event-click-handlers-free code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be trying to mix commanding and event handlers. If you want to use commanding, you should first create a viewmodel with the command defined there. Then set your datacontext in xaml to that viewmodel. Then you should be able to bind the commands the way you want to. A common approach would be to first define a RelayCommand class.

A simple relay class might look something like this:

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<T> _execute = null;
    readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="DelegateCommand{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">Delegate to execute when Execute is called on the command.  This can be null to just hook up a CanExecute delegate.</param>
    /// <remarks><seealso cref="CanExecute"/> will always return true.</remarks>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
    ///<returns>
    ///true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
    ///</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute.
    ///</summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    ///<summary>
    ///Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="parameter">Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to <see langword="null" />.</param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

That example came from this question [Why RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand)

Once you have a RelayCommand class, in your ViewModel you can define commands such as

```
 public class MainWindowViewModel
 {
       private ICommand _Command;
        public ICommand Command
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Command == null)
                    _Command = new RelayCommand<object>((x) => ExecuteCommand(x));
                return _Command;
            }
            set
            {
                _Command = value;
            }
        }

       private void ExecuteCommand(object parameter)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.ToString()){
                  //Do sql call here. parameter.ToString() is a string representation of the parameter that was bound on the xaml

               }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Now that you have that set up, just set your view's data context to the view model. You can do this in the code behind, or in the xaml, whatever you want. Something like

```
    public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
```

Now your binding in xaml to the command should look like:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="update" Command="{Binding Command}"     CommandParameter="{Binding assignment_id}"></Button>
```

However while we're here, please change your sql command to use parameters instead of concatenating it as a string like that. Doing it the way you are now will leave you open to sql injection.

Edit: it should be noted that the object you are binding to the CommandParameter should exist in your view model as well. Ideally you would have a model containing the property for assignment_id then you would instantiate a type of that model in the view model, then bind that instance of the model to your View.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the order in which the click event (btnUpdate_Click) and the command are called. If the event is called first, the variable 'p' doesn't have a value, and the query would fail.

I think you should use either the event or the command to perform the query, not both of them. if you intend to keep using the MVVM pattern (which I recommend), use the command in another class that would be your viewmodel.