# ICommand with ViewModel dependency

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand

I am searching a pattern to keep SOLID principles in my application when I use ICommand. Basically my problem is the command execution has a dependency with the view model but at the same time the view model has a dependency with the command (I inject them by constructor). I would like to keep the viewmodel with properties only, so this is an example of my current implementation:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

   public string Message { get; set; } // PropertyChanged ommited

   public MyViewModel()
   {            
   }

   public void SetCommand(ICommand myCommand)
   {
       this.MyCommand = myCommand;
   }

   ....
}

internal interface IMyViewModelCommandManager
{
    void ExectueMyCommand();
}

internal class MyViewModelCommandManager : IMyViewModelCommandManager
{
   private readOnly MyViewModel myViewModel;

   public MyViewModelCommandManager(MyViewModel myViewModel)
   {
       this.myViewModel = myViewModel;
   }

   public ExectueMyCommand()
   {
        MessageBox.Show(this.myViewModel.Message);
   }
}

internal class MyViewModelFactory: IMyViewModelFactory
{
   private readonly IContainerWrapper container;

   public MyViewModelFactory(IContainerWrapper container)
   {
      this.container = container;
   }

   public MyViewModel Create()
   {
       MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();

       IMyViewmodelCommandManager manager = this.container.Resolve<IMyViewmodelCommandManager>(new ResolverOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("viewModel", viewModel) });

       ICommand myCommand = new DelegateCommand(manager.ExecuteMyCommand);

       viewModel.SetCommand(myCommand);

       return viewModel;
   }
}
```

So, to avoid use the *SetCommand* method. I have thought two solutions but I don't know if they are elegant.

The first one is to move the viewmodel dependency from the constructor to the method updating the code in this way:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

   public string Message { get; set; } // PropertyChanged ommited

   public MyViewModel(ICommand myCommand)
   {
       this.MyCommand = myCommand;            
   }

   ....
}

internal interface IMyViewModelCommandManager
{
    void ExectueMyCommand(MyViewModel viewModel);
}

internal class MyViewModelCommandManager : IMyViewModelCommandManager
{
   public MyViewModelCommandManager()
   {
       ....
   }

   public ExectueMyCommand(MyViewModel viewModel)
   {
        MessageBox.Show(myViewModel.Message);
   }
}

internal class MyViewModelFactory: IMyViewModelFactory
{
   private readonly IContainerWrapper container;

   public MyViewModelFactory(IContainerWrapper container)
   {
      this.container = container;
   }

   public MyViewModel Create()
   {
       IMyViewmodelCommandManager manager = this.container.Resolve<IMyViewmodelCommandManager>(..);

       ICommand myCommand = new DelegateCommand<MyViewModel>(manager.ExecuteMyCommand);

       MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(myCommand);
       return viewModel;
   }
}
```

Of course, the xaml code will use CommandParameter:

```
<Button Content="Show Message" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

Other solution I have thought is to use a trick creating a Wrapper of the viewModel and the commandManager have a dependency with the Wrapper instead of the viewModel:

```
internal class MyViewModelCommandContext
   {
      public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
   }

   public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

       public string Message { get; set; } // PropertyChanged ommited

       public MyViewModel(ICommand myCommand)
       {
           this.MyCommand = myCommand;            
       }

       ....
    }

    internal interface IMyViewModelCommandManager
    {
        void ExectueMyCommand();
    }

    internal class MyViewModelCommandManager : IMyViewModelCommandManager
    {
       private readonly MyViewModelCommandContext context;

       public MyViewModelCommandManager(MyViewModelCommandContext context)
       {
           this.context = context;
           ....
       }

       public ExectueMyCommand()
       {
            MessageBox.Show(this.context.myViewModel.Message);
       }
    }

    internal class MyViewModelFactory: IMyViewModelFactory
    {
       private readonly IContainerWrapper container;

       public MyViewModelFactory(IContainerWrapper container)
       {
          this.container = container;
       }

       public MyViewModel Create()
       {
           MyViewModelCommandContext context = new MyViewModelCommandContext();

           IMyViewmodelCommandManager manager = this.container.Resolve<IMyViewmodelCommandManager>(new ResolverOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("context", context) });

           ICommand myCommand = new DelegateCommand(manager.ExecuteMyCommand);

           MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(myCommand);
           context.ViewModel = viewModel;
           return viewModel;
       }
    }
```

In my opinion the first one is the best solution for this problem, what do you think is the best solution. Would you apply another solution?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to leave the command property to `private set` and then add a method allowing anyone to set the property. You might as well just leave the command property's `set` as `public`, there's nothing wrong with that. That being said, your `ICommand` is pretty generic, it'd be very easy for someone to inject a totally unexpected command in it's place. You'd be much better of using a `RelayCommand` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand)) and keep your command logic contained within the View Model.

Comment: I have the private set because my intention is to inject the command by constructor, because I understand the command is a dependency of the viewmodel and the viewmodel mustn't know about the command logic. if I change the set to public anyone can inject unexpected command too. In my opinion is not view model responsability to keep the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your opinions.

I understand you when you say I am creating a complex pattern, but in a big project with a big developers team, if there is not clear patterns with split responsabilities, the code maintenance could be impossible to perform.

Reading you and your third solution I have thought one possible solution. It seems complexity but, in my opinion, improves the code quality. I will create a commandContext, which only have the viewmodel properties needed for the code, avoiding to have all viewmodel in the command manager. Also I will create a class whose responsability is to mantain the context updated when the viewmodel changes. This is the possible code:

```
internal class MyCommandContext
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; private set; }

    public string Message { get; set; } // PropertyChanged ommited

    public string OtherProperty { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MyChildViewModel> Childs { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel(ICommand myCommand)
    {
        this.MyCommand = myCommand;            
    }

       ....
}

internal interface IMyViewModelCommandManager
{
    void ExectueMyCommand();
}

internal class MyViewModelCommandManager : IMyViewModelCommandManager
{
   private readonly MyCommandContext context;

   public MyViewModelCommandManager(MyViewModelCommandContext context)
   {
       this.context = context;
       ....
   }

   public ExectueMyCommand()
   {
        MessageBox.Show(this.context.Message);
   }
}

internal interface IMyViewModelCommandSynchronizer
{
    void Initialize();
}

internal class MyViewModelCommandSynchronizer : IMyViewModelCommandSynchronizer, IDisposable
{
     private readOnly MyViewModel viewModel;
     private readOnly MyCommandContext context;

     MyViewModelCommandSynchronizer(MyViewModel viewModel, MyCommandContext context)
     {
         this.viewModel = viewModel;
         this.context = context;
     }

     public void Initialize()
     {
         this.viewModel.PropertyChanged += this.ViewModelOnPropertyChanged;
     }

    private void ViewModelOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Message")
        {
             this.context.Message = this.viewModel.Message;
        }
    }

    // Dispose code to deattach the events.
}

internal class MyViewModelFactory: IMyViewModelFactory
{
   private readonly IContainerWrapper container;

   public MyViewModelFactory(IContainerWrapper container)
   {
       this.container = container;
   }

   public MyViewModel Create()
   {
       MyCommandContext context = new MyCommandContext();

       IMyViewmodelCommandManager manager = this.container.Resolve<IMyViewmodelCommandManager>(new ResolverOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("context", context) });

       ICommand myCommand = new DelegateCommand(manager.ExecuteMyCommand);

       MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(myCommand);

       IMyViewModelCommandSynchronizer synchronizer = this.container.Resolve<IMyViewmodelCommandManager>(new ResolverOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("context", context), new ParameterOverride("viewModel", viewModel) });

       synchronizer.Initialize();

       return viewModel;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO both solutions are overly complicated. SOLID is great, KISS is better.

Your `MyViewModelCommandManager` is currently directly coupled to `MyViewModel` since it needs the latter's `Message`, so what is the advantage of having them separate? Why not simply implement the command inside `MyViewModel`?

If this would entail injecting too many dependencies into `MyViewModel`, then think about what you actually need the command to do, and abstract away everything else that isn't needed.

- The command displays a message.
- The message is held by `MyViewModel`
- You want to display the message outside `MyViewModel` (maybe other viewmodels also need to display a message and you want to reuse the code?)
- So all you really need is some kind of notification from `MyViewModel` that it wants to display a message, or that something has occured that would result in a message being displayed.

Possible solutions:

1. Inject an `IMessageDisplayService` to `MyViewModel`. `MyViewModel` calls it with the message.
2. Inject a callback to `MyViewModel` similar to above.
3. Have `MyViewModel` raise an event with the message as an EventArg.

The inferred responsibilities of the above solutions are subtly different.

1. means that `MyViewModel` is in charge. It wants to display a message.
2. is less explicit. `MyViewModel` knows it needs to call the callback, but doesn't really know or care what it does.
3. is like 2 but even more decoupled. Multiple things can subscribe or unsubscribe to the event but `MyViewModel` remains blissfully ignorant.

All three of these mean that the thing displaying the message has no need to know about `MyViewModel`. You have decoupled them. It's `MyViewModelFactory` that does any wiring up required.

Comment: Regarding to implement the message inside the ViewModel: a) it is harder to test as the command will be private instead of public in a different class. b) it probably offers more data to the command that the one it should be able to handle. c) over time viewmodels tend to be God-like objects with lots of responsibilities. Don't get me wrong, I recognize there is a problem here but I don't think mixing responsibilities is the proper solution.

Comment: Yes, I would agree that showing message boxes is probably not something that should live inside a VM. I was kind of assuming the message box was just a quick implementation for examples sake. Take note OP that if you really are showing message boxes then it would be better to move that functionality outside using one of the suggested alternatives. As Ignacio notes it makes testing easier since the implementation can be mocked and checked.

Comment: Exactly, This is an example. But the view model can contains twenty properties, and the command can execute an external invocation and to use several properties of the viewmodel. The example is an abstraction of a big project.