# wpf binding command to shortcut of window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a very simple solution below for tabs being populated based on MVVM. How do I setup the following two commands, and 'Add' and 'Remove'. From what I've read online it appears I need to setup ICommand or something along those lines. It wasn't clear enough to me in the demos for me to get it working.

1. The **Add** command would call the already existing function in the ViewModel class. Bu it would be called by a key command 'Ctrl + N'
2. The **Remove** command would be called when the user clicks the 'X' button, which would remove that particular tab. Otherwise it can be called by 'Ctrl + W' which would close whichever tab is currently selected.

The command stuff is new to me, so if someone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated. I hope to expand upon this and continue adding more to the tool.

Link to visual studio [dropbox files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qsvdewzubv9u5m0/WpfApplication1_share.zip?dl=0). You'll see I've broken things out to classes and organized it in a way that makes things clear.

[image]

Snippets of tool below...

**View Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabItems;

        public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems
        {
            get { return tabItems ?? (tabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>()); }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "One", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
            TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Two", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
            TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        }

        public void AddContentItem()
        {
            TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        }
    }



    public class TabItem
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:data="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="250">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <data:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--<Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Grid.Row="0"></Button>-->
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightBlue">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Button Content="x" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've received two other answers already. Unfortunately, neither precisely addresses both the **Add** and **Remove** commands. Also, one prefers to focus primarily on code-behind implementation rather than XAML declarations, and is fairly sparse on details anyway, while the other more-correctly focuses on implementation in XAML where appropriate, but does not include correct, working code, and (slightly) obfuscates the answer by introducing the extra abstraction of the `RelayCommand` type.

So, I will offer my own take on the question, with the hopes this will be more useful to you.

While I agree that abstracting the `ICommand` implementation into a helper class such as `RelayCommand` is useful and even desirable, unfortunately this tends to hide the basic mechanisms of what's going on, and requires a more elaborate implementation that was offered in the other answer. So for now, let's ignore that.

Instead, just focus on what does need to be implemented: two different implementations of the `ICommand` interface. Your view model will expose these as the values of two bindable properties representing the commands to be executed.

Here is a new version of your `ViewModel` class (with the irrelevant and unprovided `ObservableObject` type removed):

```
class ViewModel
{
    private class AddCommandObject : ICommand
    {
        private readonly ViewModel _target;

        public AddCommandObject(ViewModel target)
        {
            _target = target;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _target.AddContentItem();
        }
    }

    private class RemoveCommandObject : ICommand
    {
        private readonly ViewModel _target;

        public RemoveCommandObject(ViewModel target)
        {
            _target = target;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _target.RemoveContentItem((TabItem)parameter);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabItems;

    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems
    {
        get { return tabItems ?? (tabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>()); }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand { get { return _addCommand; } }
    public ICommand RemoveCommand { get { return _removeCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addCommand;
    private readonly ICommand _removeCommand;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "One", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Two", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        _addCommand = new AddCommandObject(this);
        _removeCommand = new RemoveCommandObject(this);
    }

    public void AddContentItem()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
    }

    public void RemoveContentItem(TabItem item)
    {
        TabItems.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Note the two added nested classes, `AddCommandObject` and `RemoveCommandObject`. These are both examples of nearly the simplest implementation of `ICommand` possible. They can always be executed, and so the return value of `CanExecute()` never changes (so there's no need to ever raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event). They do need the reference to your `ViewModel` object so that they can each call the appropriate method.

There are also two public properties added to allow binding of these commands. Of course, the `RemoveContentItem()` method needs to know what item to remove. This needs to be set up in the XAML, so that the value can be passed as a parameter to the command handler and from there to the actual `RemoveContentItem()` method.

In order to support the use of the keyboard for the commands, one approach is to add input bindings to the window. This is what I've chosen here. The `RemoveCommand` binding additionally needs the item to be deleted to be passed as the command parameter, so this is bound to the `CommandParameter` for the `KeyBinding` object (just as for the `CommandParameter` of the `Button` in the item).

The resulting XAML looks like this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <data:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="{Binding AddCommand}">
    <KeyBinding.Gesture>
      <KeyGesture>Ctrl+N</KeyGesture>
    </KeyBinding.Gesture>
  </KeyBinding>
  <KeyBinding Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=tabControl1}">
    <KeyBinding.Gesture>
      <KeyGesture>Ctrl+W</KeyGesture>
    </KeyBinding.Gesture>
  </KeyBinding>
</Window.InputBindings>

<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <TabControl x:Name="tabControl1" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightBlue">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
          <Button Content="x" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5 0 0 0"
                  Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
          </Button>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

As I mentioned above, there is in fact benefit to abstracting the `ICommand` implementation, using a helper class instead of declaring a new class for every command you want to implement. The referenced answer at [Why RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286816) mentions loose coupling and unit testing as motivations. While I agree these are good goals, I can't say that these goals are in fact served per se by the abstraction of the `ICommand` implementation.

Rather, I see the benefits as being the same ones primarily found when making such abstractions: it allows for code reuse, and in doing so improves developer productivity, along with code maintainability and quality.

In my above example, every time you want a new command, you have to write a new class that implements `ICommand`. On the one hand, this means that each class you write can be tailor-made to the specific purpose. Dealing with `CanExecuteChanged` or not, as the case requires, passing parameters or not, etc.

On the other hand, every time you write such a class, that's an opportunity to write a new bug. Worse, if you introduce a bug which is then later copy/pasted, then when you eventually find the bug, you may or may not fix it everywhere it exists.

And of course, writing such classes over and over gets tedious and time-consuming.

Again, these are just specific examples of the general conventional wisdom of the "best practice" of abstracting reusable logic.

So, if we've accepted that an abstraction is useful here (I certainly have :) ), then the question becomes, what does that abstraction look like? There are a number of different ways to approach the question. The referenced answer is one example. Here is a slightly different approach that I've written:

```
class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecuteHandler;
    private readonly Action<T> _executeHandler;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeHandler)
        : this(executeHandler, null) { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeHandler, Func<T, bool> canExecuteHandler)
    {
        _canExecuteHandler = canExecuteHandler;
        _executeHandler = executeHandler;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecuteHandler != null ? _canExecuteHandler((T)parameter) : true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeHandler((T)parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = CanExecuteChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `ViewModel` class, the above would be used like this:

```
class ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabItems;

    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems
    {
        get { return tabItems ?? (tabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>()); }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand { get { return _addCommand; } }
    public ICommand RemoveCommand { get { return _removeCommand; } }

    private readonly ICommand _addCommand;
    private readonly ICommand _removeCommand;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "One", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Two", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });

        // Use a lambda delegate to map the required Action<T> delegate
        // to the parameterless method call for AddContentItem()
        _addCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(o => this.AddContentItem());

        // In this case, the target method takes a parameter, so we can just
        // use the method directly.
        _removeCommand = new DelegateCommand<TabItem>(RemoveContentItem);
    }
```

Notes:

- Of course, now the specific `ICommand` implementations are no longer needed. The `AddCommandObject` and `RemoveCommandObject` classes have been removed from the `ViewModel` class.
- In their place, the code uses the `DelegateCommand<T>` class.
- Note that in some cases, the command handler is not going to need the parameter passed to the `ICommand.Execute(object)` method. In the above, this is addressed by accepting the parameter in a lambda (anonymous) delegate, and then ignoring it while calling the parameterless handler method. Other ways to approach this would be to have the handler method accept the parameter but then ignore it, or to have a non-generic class in which the handler delegate itself can be parameterless. IMHO, there's no "right way" per se…just various choices that may be considered more or less preferable according to personal preference.
- Note also that this implementation differs from the referenced answer's implementation in the handling of the `CanExecuteChanged` event. In my implementation, the client code is given fine-grained control over that event, at the expense of requiring the client code to retain a reference to the `DelegateCommand<T>` object in question and calling its `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method at the appropriate time. In the other implementation, it instead relies on the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event. This is a trade-off of convenience vs efficiency and, in some cases, correctness. That is, it is less convenient for the client code to have to retain references to commands which may change the executable status, but if one goes the other route, at the very least the `CanExecuteChanged` event may be raised much more often than is required, and in some cases it's even possible it may *not* be raised when it should have been (which is far worse than the possible inefficiency).

On that last point, yet another approach would be to make the `ICommand` implementation a dependency object, and provide a dependency property that is used to control the executable state of the command. This is a lot more complicated, but overall could be considered the superior solution as it allows fine-grained control over the `CanExecuteChanged` event's raising, while providing a good, idiomatic way to bind the executable state of the command, e.g. in XAML to whatever property or properties actually determine said executability.

Such an implementation might look something like this:

```
class DelegateDependencyCommand<T> : DependencyObject, ICommand
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsExecutableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsExecutable", typeof(bool), typeof(DelegateCommand<T>), new PropertyMetadata(true, OnIsExecutableChanged));

    public bool IsExecutable
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExecutableProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsExecutableProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnIsExecutableChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DelegateDependencyCommand<T> command = (DelegateDependencyCommand<T>)d;
        EventHandler handler = command.CanExecuteChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(command, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private readonly Action<T> _executeHandler;

    public DelegateDependencyCommand(Action<T> executeHandler)
    {
        _executeHandler = executeHandler;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return IsExecutable;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeHandler((T)parameter);
    }
}
```

In the above, the `canExecuteHandler` argument for the class is eliminated, in lieu of the `IsExecutable` property. When that property changes, the `CanExecuteChanged` event is raised. IMHO it's unfortunate that there is this discrepancy in the `ICommand` interface between how it's designed and how WPF normally works (i.e. with bindable properties). It's a bit weird that we have essentially a property but which is exposed via an explicit getter method named `CanExecute()`.

On the other hand, this discrepancy does serve some useful purposes, including making explicit and convenient the use of the `CommandParameter` for both the execution of the command, and the checking for executability. These are worthwhile goals. I'm just not sure personally whether I'd have made the same choice balancing them with the consistency of the usual way state is connected within WPF (i.e. through binding). Fortunately, it's simple enough to implement the `ICommand` interface in a bindable way (i.e. as above), if that's really desired.

Comment: You nailed it @Peter Duniho thank you so much for explaining the breakdown the the solution. It's much appreciated. Would you be willing to explain what benefits there are to breaking the ICommand into a helper class. And is possible could you show as an alternative how i would do that with this project?

Comment: any interest in showing the ICommand helper class as if you were doing it? I've lover to see an example of this.

Comment: @JokerMartini: yes, I'm happy to. I just don't have the time at the moment. In the meantime, you may want to review the Q&A referenced by answerer d.moncada: [Why RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286816). I don't find the discussion there as helpful as it could be, but it has a complete code example (i.e. the `RelayCommand<T>` class). You can get a head-start looking over that and seeing how it would fit as a replacement for the two special-purpose `ICommand` implementations I provided above.

Comment: alright thank you. I'll read over that in the meantime and look around on the web to better understand the ICommand / Relay command topic. In my case I'll be expanding upon the tool adding more commands. I'll be looking forward to seeing your solution as i appreciate your help.

Comment: @JokerMartini: okay, I've added a discussion regarding an abstracted implementation of `ICommand`. I trust that this can get you headed in the right direction. If not, I suggest that you formulate any concerns as specific questions which can be posted to Stack Overflow and answered by the first available respondent. :) If I see them, I'll be happy to take a look, but you may get faster response time broadening your audience.

Comment: Wow this is great stuff and in such great detail i appreciate your help and samples very much. You've done more than i could have asked for! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can start with remove.

First, you will need to create a `RelayCommand` class. More info about RelayCommand, see this post: [Why RelayCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand)

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Private members
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Action execute;

    /// <summary>
    /// True if command is executing, false otherwise
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Func<bool> canExecute;
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="RelayCommand"/> that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action execute): this(execute, canExecute: null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="RelayCommand"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when RaiseCanExecuteChanged is called.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this <see cref="RelayCommand"/> can execute in its current state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">
    /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>True if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.</returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null ? true : this.canExecute();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the <see cref="RelayCommand"/> on the current command target.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">
    /// Data used by the command. If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.
    /// </param>
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to raise the <see cref="CanExecuteChanged"/> event
    /// to indicate that the return value of the <see cref="CanExecute"/>
    /// method has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = this.CanExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, add a "bindable" Remove property in your `ViewModel` of type `RelayCommand`. This is what your `TabItem` buttons will bind to, and how it will notify the `ViewModel` it was pressed. The `ReplayCommand` will have an execute method that will get called whenever a press occurs. Here, we remove our-self from the overall `TabItem` list.

```
public class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabItems;
    private RelayCommand<object> RemoveCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems
    {
        get { return tabItems ?? (tabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>()); }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "One", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Two", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });

        RemoveCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(RemoveItemExecute);
    }

    public void AddContentItem()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() });
    }

    private void RemoveItemExecute(object param)
    {
        var tabItem = param as TabItem;
        if (tabItem != null)
        {
            TabItems.Remove(tabItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, update your XAML. Each `TabItem` will need to bind to the `RemoveCommand` in the parent `ViewModel` and pass itself in as a parameter. We can do this like:

```
<!--<Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Grid.Row="0"></Button>-->
<TabControl x:Name="TabItems" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" Grid.Row="1" Background="LightBlue">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=TabItems, Path=DataContext.RemoveCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                        Content="x" 
                        Width="20" 
                        Height="20" 
                        Margin="5 0 0 0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first u need to setup your commands

```
public static class Commands
{
    private static RoutedUICommand add;
    private static RoutedUICommand remove;

    static Commands()
    {
        searchValue = new RoutedUICommand("Add", "Add", typeof(Commands));
        showCSCode = new RoutedUICommand("Remove", "Remove", typeof(Commands));
        add.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.N, ModifierKeys.Control));
        remove.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.X));
    }

    public static RoutedUICommand Add { get { return add; } }
    public static RoutedUICommand Remove { get { return remove; } }
}
```

In window loaded event you have to bind the command methods

```
<window ... Loaded="window_loaded">
```

The cs file

```
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(Commands.Remove, HandleRemoveExecuted, HandleCanRemoveExecuted));
```

Is command enabled:

```
    private void HandleCanAddExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
```

What should the command do:

```
    private void HandleAddExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddContentItem();
    }
```

At last you just have to edit your existing files with

```
TabItems.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Three", Content = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), 
                           CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(Commands.Add, HandleAddExecuted, HandleCanAddExecuted)); });
```

xaml:

```
<Window ... 
        xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:<NAMESPACE>">
<Button Content="x" Width="20" 
        Height="20" Margin="5 0 0 0"
        Command="{x:Static commands:Commands.Remove}"/>
```