# Get the commandparameter value when clicking a button MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, command, mvvm-light

Other examples are not working or are completly different from what I do.

So I have a button on my XAML page like this:

```
 <Button Width="100"
         Height="50"
         Margin="0 0 10 0"
         Command="{Binding MenuButtonViewModel.MenuButtonCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding Parameter}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}">
```

And on my ViewModel this:

```
    public RelayCommand MenuButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
            });
        }
    }
```

The question is how do I get the value of the commandparameter on my ViewModel?

```
    public RelayCommand<String> MenuButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand((parameter) =>
            {
                 Text = parameter;
            });
        }
    }
```

This is not working, have no idea how to do this without having to use codebehind to pass the commandparameter value to the ViewModel.

Comment: This should work. Show what you have inside that `Parameter` property.

Comment: Your RelayCommand with the string parameter looks okay. That you do not get the parameter value could be caused by either the `{Binding Parameter}` binding failing, or the binding source providing a value/object that is not a string...

Comment: I get the error "Delegate 'Action' does not take 1 arguments".

Comment: Ah, yes... Try to initialize your RelayCommand like `new RelayCommand<string>( ... )`

Comment: What is your implementation of RelayCommand? Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22286816/891715

Comment: @Arie I'm using the MVVM Light libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the solution:

```
    public RelayCommand<string> Command
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand<string>(parameter =>
            {
                var str = parameter;
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks guys.