# WPF Combobox SelectedItem binding doesn't update from code

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding, selecteditem

I have this combobox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

and this is the code:

```
public class CustomComboBoxViewModel
    {
    private bool DiscardSelChanged { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (!DiscardSelChanged)
                _selectedItem = value;
            bool old = DiscardSelChanged;
            DiscardSelChanged = false;
            if (!old)
                SelectionChanged?.Invoke(_selectedItem);
        }
    }

    public event Action<string> SelectionChanged;

    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
        var v = Items.Where(x => x.Equals(item)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (v != default(string))
        {
            SelectedItem = v;
        }
        else
        {
            DiscardSelChanged = true;
            _selectedItem = item;
            Items.Insert(0, item);
        }
    }
}
```

At startup I have only one item: **Browse...**. selecting it i can browse for  a file and add its path to the ComboBox. **AddItem** method is called
If the selected file path doesn't exists in **Items** i add and select it (this is working).
If the selected file path exists in **Items** i want to automatically select it without adding it to the list again. this doesn't work and **Browse...** is the visualized item.
I already tried to use **INotifyPropertyChanged**.
I'm using .NET 4.6.2. Any ideas to get it working?

EDIT 4:barebone example

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            Items.Add(ASD);
        }
        private string ASD = @"BROWSE";
        private string _selectedItem;

        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
                UploadFileSelection_SelectionChanged();
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        private void AddItem(string item)
        {
            var v = Items.Where(x => x.Equals(item)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (v != default(string))
                SelectedItem = v;
            else
            {
                Items.Add(item);
                SelectedItem = item;
            }
        }

        private void UploadFileSelection_SelectionChanged()
        {
            if (SelectedItem == ASD)
            {
                Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
                {
                    DefaultExt = ".*",
                    Filter = "* Files (*.*)|*.*"
                };
                bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

                if (result == true)
                    AddItem(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

comboBox:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

try to:
- select FILE_A.txt
- select FILE_B.txt
- select FILE_A.txt again

Comment: *"I already tried to use INotifyPropertyChanged."* -- you did it wrong. Show us how you did it and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: question edited

Comment: Did you also write `public class CustomComboBoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: yes sorry, forgot it

Comment: The `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem))` call should be in the SelectedItem property setter, after `_selectedItem = value`

Comment: Immediately *after* a property named `X` changes its value, you **must** call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(X))`. You **must** do that in the `set` block for `X`, *after* you give the backing variable a new value. No exceptions. You must do this for every property, and you must do it in the `set` block so it always happens every time you set the property. That is what we mean by "implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`".

Comment: @Clemens Itried and it's not working. btw i can call OnPropertyChanged where i want, probably i should call it in the setter just for coding standard

Comment: @mbq Please copy the new version that isn't working and paste it into your question. We'll show you how to fix it.

Comment: You also have `_selectedItem = item` in AddItem. Replace that by `SelectedItem = item`.

Comment: As a note, `Mode=OneWay` on the ItemsSource Binding is already the default and hence redundant.

Comment: if i replace `_selectedItem = item` with `SelectedItem = item` file browse window will open twice so I can't. also set _selectedItem in that bad way (i know it's bad) is the only working solution i found

Comment: Well, that is not an option. You have to set the property, not the backing field. Get the invocation of that strange (and yet unexplained) SelectionChanged event out of the property setter.

Comment: `SelectedItem = item` is not needed because `Items.Insert(0, item);` updates the DataContext so both properties ItemsSource and SelectedItem are updated

Comment: *"if i replace _selectedItem = item with SelectedItem = item file browse window will open twice"* -- then get all that stuff out of your setter and put it someplace where it belongs. Don't do it that way. It's an anti-pattern. `SelectedItem = item` **is needed**. "Updates the DataContext" doesn't make any sense. You need to listen to what Clemens tells you, because he is an expert. What you're doing here is easy if you do it right. Let him tell you how to do it right.

Comment: just try the code you are telling me to use. i followed Clemens suggestions and it's not working. i use wpf since 5 years so I'm not a newbie

Comment: @mbq Well, if you're that knowledgeable, you can resolve this incredibly trivial issue without any great effort. Glad to hear it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i didn't mean you are wrong, i mean i already tried a lot of things. i added a barebone example

Comment: @mbq I tried your example. I fixed the re-entrancy problem (double browse dialog) with a flag. The problem you have is that `UploadFileSelection_SelectionChanged()` is called, and updates `SelectedItem` *before you exit the `SelectedItem` setter* from the call that sets it to `ASD`. So `SelectedItem = v;` in `AddItem()` has no effect on the combobox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147291/discussion-between-rmbq-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example. I fixed the re-entrancy problem (double browse dialog) with a flag:

```
private bool _browsing = false;
private void UploadFileSelection_SelectionChanged()
{
    if (_browsing)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (SelectedItem == ASD)
    {
        try
        {
            _browsing = true;
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()
            {
                DefaultExt = ".*",
                Filter = "* Files (*.*)|*.*"
            };
            bool? result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            if (result == true)
                AddItem(dlg.FileName);
        }
        finally
        {
            _browsing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It's caveman stuff but it works.

The real problem you have is that `UploadFileSelection_SelectionChanged()` is called, and updates `SelectedItem` *before you exit the `SelectedItem` setter* from the call that sets it to `ASD`.

So `SelectedItem = v;` in `AddItem()` has no effect on the combobox, because the combobox isn't responding to `PropertyChanged` right then.

This will fix that:

```
private void AddItem(string item)
{
    var v = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(item));

    if (v != default(string))
    {
        //SelectedItem = v;
        Task.Run(() => SelectedItem = v);
    }
    else
    {
        Items.Add(item);
        SelectedItem = item;
    }
}
```

Now we're doing it later.

But note that the other branch does work, the one where `item` is newly added to the collection. You can also fake it out by removing `item` and adding it again:

```
private void AddItem(string item)
{
    //  Harmless, if it's not actually there. 
    Items.Remove(item);

    Items.Add(item);
    SelectedItem = item;
}
```

That looks weirder, but since it doesn't rely on thread timing, it's probably a better solution. On the other hand, this is "viewmodel" code whose details are driven by the peculiarities of the implementation of the `ComboBox` control. That's not a good idea.

This should be probably be done in the view (leaving aside that in this contrived example our view *is* our viewmodel).

Answer (score 1):

You are setting _`selectedItem` without calling `OnPropertyChanged()` afterwards. That's why it is not working. If you want a clear code solution consider implementing the property with `OnPropertyChanged()` like this:

```
int _example;
public int Example
{
    get
    {
        return _example;
    }
    set
    {
        _example = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Example);
    }
}
```

Your code will be less error prone.

Do it as easy as possible:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; }

    public ICommand AddAnotherStringCommand { get; set; }

    string _selectedItem;
    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.SelectedItem));
        }
    }

    public int counter { get; set; } = 1;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        // RelayCommand from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand
        this.AddAnotherStringCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(AddAnotherString);
        this.Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this.Strings.Add("First item");
    }

    private void AddAnotherString(object notUsed = null)
    {
        this.Strings.Add(counter.ToString());
        counter++;
        this.SelectedItem = counter.ToString();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Main Window:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>
        <Button Content="Add another item" Command="{Binding AddAnotherStringCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In my case the value is changed every time, but you should be able to modify the code to fit your needs.

Make sure that you have a clear code structure and do not overcomplicate things.

If you want a more specific answer you should consider to present you whole code.