# WPF cant show a Template inside a DataContent

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm quite a novice to WPF and I'm pretty sure that more experienced WPF coders will be able to spot my problem within seconds.

I'm trying to show a UserControl inside a DataContent, by declaring it as a Template, but all i get instead of it is:

[image]

here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
                            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
                             <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:anotherViewViewModel}">
                                  <Views:anotherView Content="{Binding}"/>
                             </DataTemplate>
                           </ContentControl>
```

the View is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="materialDesignTesting.Views.anotherView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:materialDesignTesting.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid Background="Aqua">

  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the Model View is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace materialDesignTesting.ViewModels
{
    class anotherViewViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the ContentControl tag, the child should be a 'real' element. You can remove the DataTemplate there and insert the view allone.

Comment: @Silvermind That's not necessarily true, see my answer. Content controls are commonly used like this as navigation holders

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Ah. Forgot about that functionallity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would define a template like:

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FooVM}">
       <local:FooUserControl/>
   </DataTemplate>
```

That goes in a resource dictionary which is merged in app.xaml.
You then bind

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentProperty}"/>
```

In the viewmodel is the datacontext, ContentProperty is set to an instance of a viewmodel such as FooVM in order to navigate to foo.
When you navigate it's best to set ContentProperty to null then your new vm unless you wish to retain view state if the user navigates to the same view.

In any case, when you do this the usercontrol FooUserControl you produce from that template has the content ( your vm ) as it's datacontext.

Here's a simplified example:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object currentViewModel;

    public object CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set { currentViewModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private RelayCommand<Type> navigateCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Type> NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return navigateCommand
              ?? (navigateCommand = new RelayCommand<Type>(
                vmType =>
                {
                    CurrentViewModel = null;
                    CurrentViewModel = Activator.CreateInstance(vmType);
                }));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The view:

```
<Window x:Class="wpf_Navigation_ViewModelFirst.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf_Navigation_ViewModelFirst"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}">
        <local:LoginUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}">
        <local:UserUC/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Login Page"
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:LoginViewModel}"
                />
        <Button Content="User Page"
                Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{x:Type local:UserViewModel}"
                />
    </StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"
                    />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I added the template to the resource dictionary of the MainWindow.Xaml, and created an instance of the FooVM on the MainWindow.Xaml.cs, and binded the content control to the instance, yet the view is still not displayed at all, am I missing something else?

Comment: You also need to implement inotifypropertychanged on mainwindow. But I'd usually expect you to be using mainwindowviewmodel. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly!
My only suggestion is maybe to add an implementation of the RelayCommand in your answer.
I used this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527651/full-implementation-of-relay-command-can-it-be-applied-to-all-cases
@Andy

Answer (score 2):

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:anotherViewViewModel}">
          <Views:anotherView Content="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Is setting a `DataTemplate` as the actual content of the content control. You need the `ContentTemplate` property (or set the resources):

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:anotherViewViewModel}">
          <Views:anotherView Content="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Which only works if the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` is set to an instance of `anotherViewModel`. Since its not bound or anything in that code, I'm guessing its still null, and so won't instantiate your view.

You *could* just use `Views:anotherView` directly as @Silvermind suggests, but I suspect you are going for some sort of dynamic switching. If that's the case you want to stick with your current approach, just actually give the `ContentControl` something to display!

Relatedly, unless `anotherView` is *also* a `ContentControl` it probably doesn't have a `Content` property, so that set/binding is nonsense. `anotherView` will pick up the instance of `anotherViewModel` as its DataContext by virtue of being in a data template as you have it, no additional code required.