# C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views)

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I'm attempting to create a class & method which could be used on any window and page to change the current page displayed on the MainWindow window.

So far I got:

```
class MainWindowNavigation : MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow mainWindow;

   public void ChangePage(Page page)
    {
        mainWindow.Content = page;
    }
}
```

The main window itself:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainWindowNavigation mainWindow = new MainWindowNavigation();
        mainWindow.ChangePage(new Pages.MainWindowPage());
    }
```

Unfortunately this ends up with System.StackOverflowException.

The main reason for creating this is that I want to be able to change the mainWindow.Content from a page which is currently displayed in mainWindow.Content.

I have already reviewed MVVM but I don't think it is worth using it for a small application like this as all I want it to do is Display a Welcome Page on open, then on the side there will be few buttons. Once pressed the mainWindow.Content correctly changes to a page where a user can enter login detail and then on the button press on the login page I want to change the mainWindow.Content to a different page on successful validation of the login details entered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using MVVM is absolutely fine as it will simplify the implementation of your requirement. WPF is build to be used with the MVVM pattern, which means to make heavy use of data binding and data templates.

The task is quite simple. Create a `UserControl` (or `DataTemplate`)  for each view e.g., `WelcomePage` and `LoginPage` with their corresponding view models `WelcomePageViewModel` and `LoginPageViewModel`.

A `ContentControl` will display the pages.
The main trick is that, when using an implicit `DataTemplate` (a template resource without an `x:Key` defined), the XAML parser will automatically lookup and apply the correct template, where the `DataType` matches the current content type of a `ContentControl`. This makes navigation very simple, as you just have to select the current page from a collection of page models and set this page via data binding to the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` or `ContentPresenter`:

### Usage

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WelcomePageviewModel}">
      <WelcomPage />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type LoginPageviewModel}">
      <LoginPage />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
  
    <!-- Page navigation -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Content="Show Login Screen" 
              Command="{Binding SelectPageCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{x:Static PageName.LoginPage}" />
      <Button Content="Show Welcome Screen" 
              Command="{Binding SelectPageCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{x:Static PageName.WelcomePage}" />
    </StackPanel>
  
    <!-- 
      Host of SelectedPage. 
      Automatically displays the DataTemplate that matches the current data type 
    -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPage}" />
  <StackPanel>
</Window>
```

### Implementation

1. Create the individual page controls (the controls that host the page content). This can be a `Control`, `UserControl`, `Page` or simply a plain `DataTemplate`:

**WelcomePage.xaml**

```
    <UserControl>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

**LoginPage.xaml**

```
    <UserControl>
      <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageTitle}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

2. Create the page models:

**IPage.cs**

```
    interface IPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      string PageTitel { get; set; }
    }
```

**WelcomePageViewModel.cs**

```
    class WelcomePageViewModel : IPage
    {
      private string pageTitle;   
      public string PageTitle
      {
        get => this.pageTitle;
        set 
        { 
          this.pageTitle = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      private string message;   
      public string Message
      {
        get => this.message;
        set 
        { 
          this.message = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      public WelcomePageViewModel()
      {
        this.PageTitle = "Welcome";
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
```

**LoginPageViewModel.cs**

```
    class LoginPageViewModel : IPage
    {
      private string pageTitle;   
      public string PageTitle
      {
        get => this.pageTitle;
        set 
        { 
          this.pageTitle = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      private string userName;   
      public string UserName
      {
        get => this.userName;
        set 
        { 
          this.userName = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      public LoginPageViewModel()
      {
        this.PageTitle = "Login";
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
    }
```

3. Create an enumeration of page identifiers (to eliminate magic strings in XAML and C#):

**PageName.cs**

```
    public enum PageName
    {
      Undefined = 0, WelcomePage, LoginPage
    }
```

4. Create the `MainViewModel` which will manage the pages and their navigation:

**MainViewModel.cs**
An implementation of `RelayCommand` can be found at
*Microsoft Docs: Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern - [Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)*

```
    class MainViewModel
    {
      public ICommand SelectPageCommand => new RelayCommand(SelectPage);

      private Dictionary<PageName, IPage> Pages { get; }

      private IPage selectedPage;   
      public IPage SelectedPage
      {
        get => this.selectedPage;
        set 
        { 
          this.selectedPage = value; 
          OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      public MainViewModel()
      {
        this.Pages = new Dictionary<PageName, IPage>
        {
          { PageName.WelcomePage, new WelcomePageViewModel() },
          { PageName.LoginPage, new LoginPageViewModel() }
        };

        this.SelectedPage = this.Pages.First().Value;
      }

      public void SelectPage(object param)
      {
        if (param is PageName pageName 
          && this.Pages.TryGetValue(pageName, out IPage selectedPage))
        {
          this.SelectedPage = selectedPage;
        }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
        => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Comment: I am coming back to this over and over, every time I have to do something with WPF. It is a really nice starting point tutorial.

Comment: Are the welcome window will be destroy upon change from welcome to login?

Comment: @Luiey It depends. The state of the page is stored in the page models. In this example the pages are not "destroyed" as the models are stored in the Dictionary. This way you can navigate forward and backward between the views without losing data. If you want to destroy a view, you must remove every reference to the model e.g., by removing it from the Dictionary or by replacing the instance with a fresh one.

Comment: @BionicCode I see. Great explanations btw. I'm just curious about applying MVVM to full screen (self-service)unattended payment application(like ordering food, pay bills) whether it should use MVVM or just remain using Page Navigation as previous. Though decision to made but I love how the MVVM works actually especially when you show effort to write full MVVM pattern. Been done MVVM before but mostly single page.

Comment: @Luiey There is no reason against MVVM. It helps to separate data from UI and gives your application a nice structure that perfectly extends into the WPF framework. Any structure is better than no structure. If you write unit tests for your application, you can't get away from MVVM or any similar pattern.

Comment: And what if I want that the navigation buttons be part of my  Login and Welcome Views. And the relaycommand should be the on the proper ViewModels (Login, Welcome). How should i do that?

Comment: @bazsisz You have options. You can create a parent frame, like in this example. this way the navigation buttons are available in all screens. Or you move the buttons to the individual views. In this case I recommend working with routed commands and then delegate the routed command in the parent view (where you handle it) to the main view model or whatever view model host the navigation logic.

Comment: @bazsisz Another option is to create navigation service: you move the navigation logic to a dedicated navigation service class and then distribute a shared instance of this service to all screen view models. This service exposes navigation methods that the relaycommands can call. do not share the main view model with its child models.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to define `MainWindowNavigation` as a static class with a method that simply changes the `Content` of the current `MainWindow`:

```
static class MainWindowNavigation
{
    public static void ChangePage(Page page)
    {
        var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (mainWindow != null)
            mainWindow.Content = page;
    }
}
```

You can then call the method from any class without having a reference to the `MainWindow`:

```
MainWindowNavigation.ChangePage(new Pages.MainWindowPage());
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution how to do simplified navigation without storing all object initialization in memory. In my opinion, this solution allows you to save `MVVM` pattern and achieve less memory overhead.

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Background="Green">
    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <Button Content="Go to login" Command="{Binding NavigateCmd}" CommandParameter="{x:Type local:LoginPage}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedContent, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="200"/>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

### MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public partial class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
private object? content;

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    NavigateCmd = new RelayCommand<object>(Navigate);
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string? name = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}

public object? SelectedContent { get => content; set { content = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }

public RelayCommand<object> NavigateCmd { get; }
private void Navigate(object? param = null)
{
    if (param is Type type == false) return;
    SelectedContent = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    ((FrameworkElement)SelectedContent).DataContext = this; //could be any data context;
}
}
```

### LoginPage.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="TestWpf.LoginPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpf"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="LoginPage">

<Grid Background="Red">
    
</Grid>
```

When button "Go to login" will be clicked it will call the `NaviateCmd` command, which in turn will call the method `Navigate` and pass the `Type` of `Page` which you would like to display inside `MainWindow.xaml`. Then inside method `Navigate` we create the instance of our page, set the necessary data binding and place it in the `SelectedContent` property.

If you want to set navigation to a different page, you can pass in the `CommandParameter` property of the `Button` a different `Type` of desired page.

- [RelayCommand implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529346/21086817)
- [INotifyPropertyChanged implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)