# C# WPF - Passing IConfiguration to Page's ViewModel from Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I can easily pass in an IConfiguration appsettings.json to a Window in WPF, which is what I have done in the past.
Now I am trying to do this the proper way and pass it into a ViewModel that is assigned as the DataContext of a Page that is being displayed on a Window.
I'm loading the Page into a Frame on the Window.
I would like to pass the config to the ViewModel of the Page so I dont have to reread it in manually.

Here is what I currently have and some stuff I tried:

```
    public partial class HomeWindow : Window
    {
        readonly IConfiguration _config;
        
        public HomeWindow(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;

            // Instantiate the Object with JSON settings.
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new HomeWindowVM(config)
        } 
    }


    public class HomeWindowVM
    {
        readonly IConfiguration _config;
        //public INotify btnCheckoutPage { get; set; }
        public object MyFrameContent { get; set; }

        public HomeWindowVM(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            CheckoutClickCommand = new MyCommand(CheckoutClick);
            ShipmentClickCommand = new MyCommand(ShipmentClick);
            frameURI = new INotify();
            frameVis = new INotify();
            frameVis.MyProperty = "Hidden";
        }

        private void CheckoutClick()
        {
            frameURI.MyProperty = "CheckoutPage.xaml";
            frameVis.MyProperty = "Visible";
// I tried this 
            //CheckoutPage checkoutPage = new CheckoutPage(_config);
            //MyFrameContent = new CheckoutPage(_config);

        }
    }


    public partial class CheckoutPage : Page
    {
        readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public CheckoutPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new CheckoutPageVM();
        }
        public CheckoutPage(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            InitializeComponent();

            //Frame frame = new Frame();
            //MainView 
            DataContext = new CheckoutPageVM(config);
        }
    }


    public class CheckoutPageVM 
    {
        readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public CheckoutPageVM(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            LblErrorProjectNum = new INotify();
            LblErrorProjectNum.MyProperty = "Hidden";
            LblErrorTransfer = new INotify();
            LblErrorTransfer.MyProperty = "Hidden";
            CheckoutSubmitCommand = new MyCommand(CheckoutSubmit);            
        }
```

Comment: what about using framecontentloaded event to pass whatever you want to that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no one proper way to do this, but I'm guessing you've got a background in ASP.NET and are familiar with dependency injection. Of course WPF doesn't use that pattern and it's probably overkill in this case. A statically accessible singleton works perfectly fine and avoids the morass of passing the config instance around through constructors or other over-engineered solutions:

```
// In your Model layer
public static class MyConfiguration
{
     public static IConfiguration Instance { get; private set; }

     public static void Load(IConfiguration config) 
     {
          // call this when the app initializes
          Instance = config;
     }
}
```

Then if individual classes need instance properties for binding, etc., it's as simple as:

```
public partial class HomeWindow : Window
{
    public IConfiguration Config => MyConfiguration.Instance;
    // ...
}

public class CheckoutPageVM 
{
    public IConfiguration Config => MyConfiguration.Instance;
    // ...
}

public partial class CheckoutPage : Page
{
    public IConfiguration Config => MyConfiguration.Instance;
    // ...
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your view should not depend on any application setting models. For this reason, the dependency of your `Window` and `Page` instances on an `IConfiguration` object in an MVVM application is wrong. Configuration is part of the application *Model*.
To avoid such dependencies the best way is to use the so called *View-Model-First* pattern. The pattern requires that your *View Model* classes decide which *View* class to load. This is the opposite behavior of your current *View-First* pattern where the *View* decides which *View Model* to load.

*View-Model-First* is usually implemented by binding a *View Model* class to the *View* (for example a `ContentPresenter` or `ContentControl` or a derived class). Then define a `DataTemplate` that will be loaded and rendered by the framework based on the current data type (view model type). This `DataTemplate` contains the actual view you want to show.
This eliminates the dependency of the *View* on *Model* classes (which in this case is introduced by allowing the view to construct its *View Model* classes explicitly.
You can check this example to get an idea on *View-Model-First*: [C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792).

For this reasons I recommend to change your approach and implement the MVVM friendly *View-Model-First* pattern.
Even if you don't implement the MVVM pattern you will achieve an application that is easier to maintain and to extend.

Whether you use *View-First* or *View-Model-First*, the `IConfiguration` instance must come from the application *Model*.
First fix or improvement of your current code is to move the `IConfiguration` instantiation to the *Model*. The *View Model* must get such application data from the *Model* and not the *View*. For this purpose the example creates an `ConfigurationRepositoty` class that encapsulates creation of `IConfiguration` instances. Because data persistence is also part of the *Model* the `ConfigurationRepositoty` has easy access to the resources like files or database. Ideally, it would use other *Model* classes that know in detail how to get the data (read from file or database).
`ConfigurationRepositoty` is either created directly in the *View Model* class or injected via the constructor (in case of implementing any IoC like the *Dependency Injection* pattern).

Regarding view model constructor dependencies, you should introduce a factory where the view model has constructor dependencies. Consider to implement the *Abstract Factory* pattern. A result of your *View-First* implementation is that the *View* instantiates the views explicitly and therefore would have to know all the dependencies in order to satisfy the constructors.
Because the dependencies of *View Model* classes are usually *Model* classes, those dependencies when declared in the *View* are illegal or compromising in terms of design. When using factories (or abstract factories), those dependencies are eliminated.

The second mandatory fix is to move the page navigation from *View Model* to the *View*.
Because you implement a *View-First* navigation, you navigate by creating instances of views or by explicitly knowing them by their URI.
But your *View Model* must not know/depend on *View* types or their URIs. This disqualifies them to act as a navigation controller.
If you want to navigate from the *View Model* then implement the *View-Model-First* pattern.

Lastly, the `MyFrameContent` property looks highly suspicious too. Based on the name it appears that the owner view model class has too much knowledge about the view, maybe even concrete dependencies.

**ConmfigurationRepository.cs**
A *Model* class that knows how to obtain or create the `IConfiguration` instance.

```
public class ConmfigurationRepository
{
  private static Lazy<IConfiguration> SharedConfiguration { get; } 
    = new Lazy<IConfiguration>(InitializeSharedConfiguration);

  public IConfiguration GetApplicationConfiguration() 
    => this.SharedConfiguration;

  // In case there are different implementations of IConfiguration
  // for example when there are different configuration contexts
  // then expose a related API
  public IConfiguration GetHomePageConfiguration()
  {
    // TODO::Create or get a new/shared IConfiguration instance.
    // If the configuration comes from an external source like a file or database,
    // then this is the place to read it (using related classes or services)
  }

  private static IConfiguration InitializeSharedConfiguration()
  {
    // TODO::Create or get a new/shared IConfiguration instance.
    // If the configuration comes from an external source like a file or database,
    // then this is the place to read it (using related classes or services)
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private void ShowView(string viewName)
  {
    Page destinationPage = viewName switch
    {
      nameof(HomePage) => CreateHomeView(),
      nameof(CheckoutPage) => CreateCheckoutView(),
      _ => throw new ArgumentException("View not found", nameof(viewName)),
    };

    // Show view
    this.frame.Content = destinationPage;
  }

  private Page CreateHomeView()
  {
    // If HomePageVM has constructor dependencies 
    // use a factory to instantiate the type
    HomePageVM homePageVm = new HomePageVM();
    var homeView = new HomeView(homePageVm);
    homeView.NavigationRequested += OnNavigationRequested;

    return homeView;
  }

  private Page CreateCheckoutView()
  {
    // If CheckoutPageVM has constructor dependencies 
    // use a factory to instantiate the type
    CheckoutPageVM checkoutPageVm = new CheckoutPageVM();

    return new CheckoutPage(checkoutPageVm);
  }

  private void OnNavigationRequested(object sender, NavigationRequestedEventArgs e)
  {
    var navigationSource = (INavigationSource)sender;
    navigationSource.NavigationRequested -= OnNavigationRequested;
    ShowView(e.DestinationViewName);
  }
}
```

**HomePage.cs**

```cs
public partial class HomePage : Page, INavigationSource
{        
  public HomeWindow(HomePageVM homePageVM)
  { 
    InitializeComponent();

    homePageVM.CheckedOut += OnCheckedOut;
    this.DataContext = homePageVM;
  } 

  private void OnCheckedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ((HomePageVM)this.DataContext).CheckedOut -= OnCheckedOut;
    OnNavigationRequested(nameof(CheckoutPage));
  }

  private void OnNavigationRequested(string destinationViewName)
    => this.NavigationRequested?.Invoke(this, new NavigationRequestedEventArgs(destinationViewName));
}
```

**CheckoutPage.cs**

```cs
public partial class CheckoutPage : Page, INavigationSource
{        
  public CheckoutPage(CheckoutPageVM checkoutPageVM)
  { 
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = checkoutPageVM;
  } 
}
```

**INavigationSource.cs**
To be implemented by all pages that need to navigate away.

```cs
public interface INavigationSource
{
  public event EventHandler<NavigationRequestedEventArgs> NavigationRequested;
}
```

**NavigationRequestedEventArgs.cs**

```cs
public class NavigationRequestedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public DestinationViewName DestinationViewName { get; }

  public NavigationRequestedEventArgs(string destinationViewName)
  {
    this.DestinationViewName = destinationViewName;
  }
}
```

**HomePageVM.cs**

```cs
public class HomePageVM
{
  readonly IConfiguration _config;

  public HomePageVM()
  {
    _config = new ConmfigurationRepository().GetApplicationConfiguration();
    CheckoutClickCommand = new MyCommand(ExecuteCheckoutCommand);
    ShipmentClickCommand = new MyCommand(ShipmentClick);  
  }

  private void ExecuteCheckoutCommand()
    => OnCheckedOut();

  private void OnCheckedOut()
    => this.CheckedOut?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

**CheckoutPageVM.cs**

```cs
public class CheckoutPageVM
{
  readonly IConfiguration _config;

  public CheckoutPageVM()
  {
    _config = new ConmfigurationRepository().GetApplicationConfiguration();
  }
}
```