# What is the proper view to initialize the child view viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a big view with a huge ViewModel that handles all the functionality for that view.
A huge ViewModel is obviously a bad approach.

I want to split the view into many more "specialized" views, but I'm deciding how should I initialize their view models.

Those small views should/will receive the IDs of objects they will work on and somehow pass them to their viewmodels so that viewmodels can pull required objects from a database.

This is how I see it now:

When the child view receives the ID/IDs (it is set as a dependency property), it calls its ViewModel method, which does all the initialization job.

The question is: Isn't it an anti-pattern and breakage of the MVVM patterns?

ParentView.xaml

```xml
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:ParentViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ChildView
            ChildObjectId="{Binding ChildObjectId}"
        />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ChildView.xaml

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:ChildViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
       ....
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ParentViewModel.cs

```cs
public partial class ParentViewModel 
{
  public ParentViewModel ()
  {
    // somehow set the value for ChildObjectId
  }

  public int ChildObjectId {get;set;}
}
```

ChildViewModel.cs

```cs
public class ChildViewModel
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildObjectIdProperty = 
  DependencyProperty.Register(
     nameof(ChildObjectId), typeof(int), typeof(RenewalItemDetailsPersonal), new PropertyMetadata(default(int))
  );

  public int ChildObjectId
  {
      get { return (int)GetValue(ChildObjectIdProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ChildObjectIdProperty, value); }
  }
 
  public ChildViewModel
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: There should be a master or main view model that contains a set of child view models. The child view models would be initialized from the main view model. Then a child view would get a child view model assigned by means of its DataContext. The child views would not have any private view models of their own.

Comment: I updated the question. How am I supposed to init `ChildViewModel` from `ParentViewModel` if `ChildView` is a part of the `ParentView`?

Comment: The UserControl should **not** have a fixed instance as you show

Comment: The view model structure should reflect the view structure. ChildViewModel would be initialized from ParentViewModel without knowing anything about the view, otherwise it wouldn't be MVVM.

Comment: As said in "*the child views would not have any private view models of their own*", a UserControl would not set its own DataContext. This is a common programming error, because it breaks the way how `{Binding ChildObjectId}` works.

Comment: The ChildViewModel should not have a DependencyProperty but implement INPC

Comment: Instead of a ChildObjectId property, ParentViewModel would have a property like `public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel { get; }`. The binding would then look like this: `<ChildView1 DataContext="{Binding ChildViewModel}" />`.

Comment: Thank you, @Clemens. This is what I was looking for. Would you consider answering the question instead of commenting so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: This question is opinion based and that is off-topic on SO and so it will be closed soon. But I post an example for you [@github](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-77577469-InitChildViewModel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid talking about opinions I will answer your questions based on the design rules imposed by the MVVM design pattern. A design pattern is a precise set of design rules with the goal to solve a very specific problem.

> *" have a big view with a huge ViewModel that handles all the functionality for that view. A huge ViewModel is obviously a bad
> approach."*

I think you misunderstand the concept of MVVM and that your problem, how to fix big view model files, stems from that.
There is a widespread misconception that in MVVM the View Model is a class, a monolithic type. But like the View and the Model the View Model is an architecture level component that contains multiple classes, a set of types. You name the main window `MainWindow` and a save file dialog `SaveFileDialog` based on the control's purpose or functionality. And a `TextBox` is a box for text. You don't name it `View` and cramp all UI elements into it.
You separate concerns and create multiple classes. But when it comes to the View Model, people think that the View Model is a single class...

To fix big classes you apply certain OO principle, for example, single-responsibility (the "S" in SOLID), Seperation of Concerns, encapsulation to name the most effective. The main goal is to identify responsibilities and extract them to a new class. This new class can then be referenced by the original class that had too many responsibilities and grew too big because of that. For example, your `DataContext` class has to convert between data models of the Model and View Model, then move this responsibility/implementation to a new class and reference it. This way you will significantly reduce the number of lines of code. In the end, a class can become big. If you can't change it, then so may it be. Common functionality should be moved to a common base class (inheritance) or encapsulated and referenced (composition). Beside from eliminating duplicate code those techniques will also reduce lines of code.

The size of a "view model" depends on the UI: the "view model" is the `DataContext` of the UI. If the `DataContext` is "big" (because the UI has a lot of responsibility - too many?), then these responsibilities are automatically imposed on the data context ("view model").
This means the first step is to *design* the UI properly. Do not cramp too much functionality into a single screen. To improve the user experience (UX) you not only design the layout, but you also structure your UI/views wisely.

A single page application is a famous concept. You partition the UI into pages, where each serves a particular task or user story (whereby a user story can also be split across multiple views). For example, a login view, a settings view etc. Each view/page usually describes or works on a particular data context. For example, a login page will work on user data like credentials. So, the data context is login related. You usually implement every such data context as a dedicated class. You can use the -ViewModel suffix to name this class. But use common OO programming principles to design this data context class with the goal to create extensible and maintainable types.
It's ok when your View Model contains hundreds of classes, as this only means you have a complex application and well-designed classes. And it's ok when you did your best to reduce the lines of code of a class and still end up with a huge class. This can happen.

Fix: design UI properly, apply OO design principles.

> *"I want to split the view into many more "specialized" views, but I'm deciding how should I initialize their view models."*

This depends on your structure and can vary from context to context. First, view model classes can be *instantiated* by classes of the View and View Model. For example, follow the Information Hiding principle to get an idea who should instantiate what. When you use dependency injection instantiation is done by the DI container. *Initialization* on the other hand can only occur in the View Model. Because for initialization we need data, and we get this data from the Model and the MVVM dependency rule strictly forbids the View to talk to the Model. Instantiation --> View or View Model, initialization --> View Model.

The most common approach is to use composition and compose a main view model of many specialized view models (data context classes). This is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792) for a single page application that uses composition and shows how to instantiate views based on the data context.

> *"Those small views should/will receive the IDs of objects they will work on and somehow pass them to their viewmodels so that viewmodels
> can pull required objects from a database."*

It's important that the View Model does not have direct data access. Application data is the domain of the Model. The View Model gets data from the Model.

> *"When the child view receives the ID/IDs (it is set as a dependency property), it calls its ViewModel method, which does all the
> initialization job."*

You definitely don't want to have a dedicated data context for every child controls. This doesn't make sense. If you think about view models as data contexts you will understand that the child controls *must* share the same data context of the parent! Otehrwise, there won't be the parent-child relationship. For example, why would you design a `UserControl` that has multiple responsibilities? That's a design flaw in terms of UX and class design. Of course, the `UserControl` has a responsibility and the child controls, that the `UserControl` is composed of, serve the only purpose to fulfill this responsibility.

> *"The question is: Isn't it an anti-pattern and breakage of the MVVM patterns?"*

Yes, if every `UserControl` and every child of the `UserControl` has its own data context class, then you are implementing an anti-pattern. But it does not break the MVVM design rules, because MVVM is not concerned about `UserControl` and child controls. MVVM is only about application structure (the Model-View Model- View components and application types associations with those components) and the dependency between those components. Generally, having the View to reference the View Model is correct MVVM. Therefore, having a class of the view call methods on a class of the View Model is correct MVVM too. And a view model class that initializes another view model class is correct MVVM as well.

Bottom line is to not get tangled up with MVVM. MVVM is an extremely simple architectural design pattern. It only describes three application components and their relationship (dependencies). The most complicated part is to identify the correct association of types with the correct MVVM component based on responsibilities. Beside complying to that application-level design rules, you design classes as usual by applying OO design principles and other design patterns.
MVVM is not concerned with class-level details. Therefore, design decisions for classes cannot be based on MVVM. Think of your -ViewModel classes as UI data context classes. This helps to identify when it's time to create a new data context class. Because a data context is the context of a view, data context classes are designed with the UI structure in mind. Big unorganized views with multiple responsibilities result in huge data context classes that have to mirror all those responsibilities in order to serve them. A bad UI design therefore creates a lot of code smells. Well organized views in a paged application (e.g., single page application) result in smaller data context class naturally. OO principles help to further improve the class design of the View Model classes.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful and detailed response. Of course, I don't want every UserControl to have its data context. I only want to extract those with different responsibilities, like one for managing client contacts, another for managing client vehicles, etc.