# How to set DataContext properly when changing the entire view to another user control in MVVM

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I would like to know what is the proper MVVM approach when I want to change the entire view to another view.

My main concern is setting the user control's `DataContext` to the preferred view model. I have read that setting the `DataContext` directly is not always the best idea, so I wonder how else I can do it, what are the alternatives?

I have tried to searched for a good solution on the web, but so far haven't found a good answer.

Comment: You would typically not set a UserControl's DataContext manually at all. Instead, different controls for differenty types of view models would be declared inside DataTemplate resources that have their DataType property set appropriately. Then simply assign different view model objects to the Content property of a ContentControl. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your question relates to topics on implementing navigation in an application. There are two main approaches:

1. Using various Page (in a Window or Frame) and navigation methods to change Page;
2. Using different UserControls that are either explicitly replaced or "automatically" replaced depending on the type of the current Data Context.

An example of a simple UI navigator with an explicit changeable UserControl:

```cs
    /// <summary>A type containing a UserControl and its name.</summary>
    public class NameForUC
    {
        /// <summary>Display name.</summary>
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>UserControl</summary>
        public UserControl Value { get; set; }
    }
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="CyberForum.UIListBoxNavigator.ListBoxNavigator"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CyberForum.UIListBoxNavigator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ListBoxNavigator" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
                 SelectedIndex="0">
            <local:NameForUC DisplayName="Begin">
                <local:NameForUC.Value>
                    <local:OnePageUC/>
                </local:NameForUC.Value>
            </local:NameForUC>
            <local:NameForUC DisplayName="End">
                <local:NameForUC.Value>
                    <local:TwoPageUC/>
                </local:NameForUC.Value>
            </local:NameForUC>
        </ListBox>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                          Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox}">
            <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:NameForUC">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Value}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You can take the implementation details and the project with source codes from here (topic in Russian): https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2564584.html#post14145160

If you give more details and explanations of your task, provide a minimal example of ViewModel and View with explanations of how you want them to interact, I am sure that you can get more specific advice on choosing an implementation option specifically for your task.

Here is another example of implementing a view change depending on the type of the current data context.

```cs
namespace Core2023.Navigators
{
    public class LocatorNavigator : ViewModelBase
    {
        public object Current { get => Get<object>(); set => Set(value); }

        public RelayCommand SetCurrent => GetCommand<object>(obj => Current = obj);
    }

    public class TextVM
    {
        public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

    public class NumberVM
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```xml
    <Application.Resources>
        <navigators:TextVM x:Key="textVM" Text="navigators:TextVM x:Key=textVM"/>
        <navigators:NumberVM x:Key="numberVM" Number="999888"/>
        <navigators:LocatorNavigator
            x:Key="navigator"
            Current="{StaticResource textVM}"/>
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Core2023.Navigators.TextUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.Navigators"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <d:UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:TextVM Text="Some Text"/>
    </d:UserControl.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid Background="LightYellow"
                 Rows="1">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Margin="10">
            <Run Text="Text:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox>
        <Button Margin="10"
                Content="Go to NumberVM"
                Command="{Binding SetCurrent, Source={StaticResource navigator}}"
                CommandParameter="{StaticResource numberVM}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </UniformGrid>
</UserControl>
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Core2023.Navigators.NumberUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.Navigators"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <d:UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:NumberVM Number="12345678"/>
    </d:UserControl.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid Background="LightCoral"
                 Rows="1">
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Margin="10">
            <Run Text="Number:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding Number, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox>
            <Button Margin="10"
                Content="Go to TextVM"
                Command="{Binding SetCurrent, Source={StaticResource navigator}}"
                CommandParameter="{StaticResource textVM}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </UniformGrid>
</UserControl>
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2023.Navigators.TextNumberWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2023.Navigators"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TextNumberWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Content="{Binding Current, Source={StaticResource navigator}}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TextVM}">
            <local:TextUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NumberVM}">
            <local:NumberUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

If the data context types are the same and the view needs to be selected based on the value of the data context property, then it is better to use the [DataTemplateSelector Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)