# Passing data between pages in wpf-ui library when navigated to a page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on an MVVM application using the [wpf-ui library](https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui).

I'd like to navigate between pages and pass a `DataMod` class as an argument to the `ModPage` page when navigating to it from my `ModRepository` page, however the library's `INavigationAware` interface doesn't seem to support passing parameters.

Ideally, I want to:
Click on a mod button inside `ModRepository` -> Pass `DataMod` as an argument then save it inside my viewmodel -> Navigate to the `ModPage` -> Bind UI stuff from the `DataMod` argument.

I have thought about using a shared service to pass the data, but I'm not sure on how I would efficiently implement it.

Comment: From your question its not clear how your code looks like. However, you don't need any library to implement content navigation. You can follow this simple example (or other similar ones) which will give you full control over the implementation details: [C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a **____ViewModel** and AddSingleton it, and inject it in
   both your pages.
2. Add a property to **____ViewModel** that both pages can use
3. finally, before navigating, change the value of the property.

- I am not sure if this is the best solution, but it is good.

Comment: I played around with this a bit and it worked, thank you!