# Setting DataContext in WPF outside of App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `MainWindow` that displays `LoginView`, `SignUpView` and `StoreView`. The `DataContext` is working fine here.

Inside the `StoreView` it should display a couple of other views with the default being `HomeView`.

How do I set that DataContext given that I use commands and MVVM

StoreView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OBOS.Views.StoreView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OBOS.Views"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:OBOS.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="640" Width="1200">
    <Border Background="AntiqueWhite"
            CornerRadius="20">
        <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            
            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:HomeViewModel}">
                        <local:HomeView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:CartViewModel}">
                        <local:CartView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:HistoryViewModel}">
                        <local:HistoryView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SearchViewModel}">
                        <local:SearchView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding StoreCurrentViewModel}"/>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

StoreViewModel:

```
public class StoreViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly NavigationStore _storeNavigationStore;
        public ViewModelBase StoreCurrentViewModel => _storeNavigationStore.CurrentViewModel;


        public ICommand ToLogin { get; }
        public ICommand ToHistory { get; }
        public ICommand ToCart { get; }
        public ICommand ToHome { get; }
        public ICommand SearchCommand { get; }

        public StoreViewModel(NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            _storeNavigationStore = new NavigationStore();
            _storeNavigationStore.CurrentViewModel = new HomeViewModel(_storeNavigationStore);

            _storeNavigationStore.CurrentViewModelChanged += OnCurrentViewModelChanged;

            ToLogin = new ToLogin(navigationStore);
            ToHistory = new ToHistory(_storeNavigationStore);
            ToCart = new ToCart(_storeNavigationStore);
            SearchCommand = new SearchCommand(_storeNavigationStore);
            ToHome = new ToHome(_storeNavigationStore);
        }

        private void OnCurrentViewModelChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StoreCurrentViewModel));
        }

    }
```

And here is the HomeCommand:

```
public class ToHome : CommandBase
    {
        private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;

        public ToHome(NavigationStore navigationStore)
        {
            _navigationStore = navigationStore;
        }

        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = new HomeViewModel(_navigationStore);
        }
    }
```

All commands behave in the same way as this one.

Now, all the views that the StoreView displays lack a DataContext, how do I fix this?

Comment: "*How do I set that DataContext*" - not at all. With `<ContentControl Content="{Binding StoreCurrentViewModel}"/>` the DataContext of the UserControls that are declared in the DataTemplates will automatically be set to the value of the StoreCurrentViewModel property. This requires that the UserControls do not explicitly set their own DataContext.

Comment: [C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just set the `StoreCurrentViewModel` property of the `StoreViewModel` to a `CartViewModel`/`HistoryViewModel`/`SearchViewModel` to display the `CartViewM`/`HistoryView`/`SearchView`.

The view will automatically inherit its `DataContext` from the `Content` property of the `ContentControl`. You should not set the `DataContext` explicitly.

Comment: This is what I did in the `StoreViewModel` constructor, but in the `HomeView`'s constructor in the code behind the DataContext is null

Comment: @CoverBasha The DataContext (as other properties) is set later, after the constructor has run. You can check the value in a Loaded or DataContextChanged event handler.

Comment: Ohh ok, now it works