# Adding to a canvas in another XAML file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, datagrid

I am trying to add a grid and a label to both canvases simultaneously.
Adding to the Pages canvas from page.xaml.cs **works** but adding to "CellPageSettings" canvas also from page.xaml.cs to cells.xaml **doesn't work**.

The count after adding gives me the impression it worked but when I got to cells.xaml there is nothing added and count is 0.

Any pointers appreciated

Below are the design pages for the 2 XAML files.

Page.XAML

```
<UserControl xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:test.Languages"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.ViewModels"
  xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:test.Converters" 
  xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:test.Enums" 
  x:Class="test.Views.PagesPage"
  x:Name="PagesPageControl" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:PagesPageViewModel x:Key="xamlViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="grid" DataContext="{DynamicResource xamlViewModel}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TabControl Background="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="0">
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" Header="Pages">
            <DockPanel>
                <Canvas x:Name="Pages" Background="LightGray">
                    <!-- Your content for the first area goes here -->
                </Canvas>
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10">
 <Button x:Name="createNewPage" Style="{StaticResource StandardBtn}" Width="120" Click="createNewPage_Click" Margin="10,0,0,10">
     <TextBlock Text="Create New Page" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
 </Button>
</StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Cells.XAML

```
<UserControl xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:test.Languages"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.ViewModels"
  xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:test.Converters" 
  xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:test.Enums" 
  x:Class="test.Views.PagesPage"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid x:Name="grid" DataContext="{DynamicResource xamlViewModel}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TabControl Background="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="0">
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" Header="CellPages">
        <DockPanel>
         <Canvas x:Name="CellPageSettings" Background="LightGray">
               <!-- Your content for the first area goes here -->
          </Canvas>
           </DockPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Page.xaml.cs - code to add to both canvases

```
 public partial class PagesPage : UserControl
 {
    public CellSettingsPage CellSettingsPage { get; private set; }

public PagesPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  CellSettingsPage = new CellSettingsPage();
}

    private void createNewPage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      AddDefaultGridToCanvas();
    }

    private void AddDefaultGridToCanvas()
    {
     numRows = Convert.ToInt32(rowSlider.Value);
     numColumns = Convert.ToInt32(columnSlider.Value);

     //NEEDS tidying up - move to a method - duplicated
     // Create a new DataGrid
     DataGrid newDataGrid = CreateDataGrid(numRows, numColumns);  
     //Creates the grid

     // Create a label for the name
     Label nameLabel = new Label
     {
         Name = currentDateTime,
         Content = "",
         // Set the name as per your requirement
         VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
         HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
         Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0) // Adjust margins as needed
     };

     double top = Pages.Children.Count > 0 ? CalculateTotalHeight() : 0; // Adjust the spacing as needed
     double left = 0; //Pages.Children.Count > 0 ? CalculateTotalWidth() : 0; // Adjust as needed

     Canvas.SetTop(newDataGrid, top);
     Canvas.SetLeft(newDataGrid, left);

     double rowHeight = top + numRows * (newDataGrid.RowHeight + 1); // Adjust this based on the actual row height of your DataGrid
     double verticalOffset = Pages.Children.Count > 0 ? rowHeight + 1 : rowHeight; // Adjust the spacing as needed

     Canvas.SetTop(nameLabel, verticalOffset);

     Pages.Children.Add(newDataGrid);
     Pages.Children.Add(nameLabel);

     //Adding to CellSettings Canvas from here - NOT WORKING
     Canvas cellSettingsCanvas = CellSettingsPage.GetCellPageSettingsCanvas();

     DataGrid newDataGridForCellSettings = CreateDataGrid(numRows, numColumns);
     Label nameLabelForCellSettings = new Label
     {
         Name = currentDateTime,
         Content = "",
         VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
         HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
         Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0)
     };

     Canvas.SetTop(newDataGridForCellSettings, top);
     Canvas.SetLeft(newDataGridForCellSettings, left);

     double verticalOffsetForCellSettings = cellSettingsCanvas.Children.Count > 0 ? rowHeight + 1 : rowHeight;
     Canvas.SetTop(nameLabelForCellSettings, verticalOffsetForCellSettings);

     cellSettingsCanvas.Children.Add(newDataGridForCellSettings);
     cellSettingsCanvas.Children.Add(nameLabelForCellSettings);
     cellSettingsCanvas.InvalidateVisual();
     cellSettingsCanvas.UpdateLayout();

    int count = cellSettingsCanvas.Children.Count; //shows 2
    Visibility visibility = cellSettingsCanvas.Visibility; // Visible
 }
```

}

cells.xaml.cs

```
public partial class CellSettingsPage : UserControl 
{
   
 public Canvas GetCellPageSettingsCanvas()
 {
    return CellPageSettings;
 }
}
```

CellPageSettings.Children.Count // shows 0
CellPageSettings.Visibility = Visible

[image: Page Canvas]

Comment: You must show the complete code that is necessary to reproduce the issue.  Maybe you were getting the wrong Canvas or working on wrong instances. Why don't use data binding? This would significantly simplify your code and likely fix the error as you won't have to handle any Canvas or DataGrid controls explicitly. It's actually a code smell to make one page handle the elements of another page. That's quite ugly. And obviously the reason for the issue. I hardly doubt that both pages are loaded simultaneously, hence you are not modifying the correct Page (Cells) instance.

Comment: And why are you using a Canvas in the first place? You are actually stacking DataGrids. This can be achieved much more easily by using a StackPanel or even better a ListBox. The latter is an excellent choice if you want to populate your UI gracefully using templates.

Comment: You must provide a shared data context that both Page instances can use/reference. I recommend fixing your design as suggested previously. This will fix all your related issues.

Comment: @BionicCode - there is only 1 canvas on both pages - I do agree that both pages aren't loaded simultaneously but there must be a way to achieve this?

As I am dynamically creating UI elements and adding them to canvases, databinding might not be the most straightforward approach, as it typically works with predefined data models.

I will take on board your suggestions around using a ListBox.

I want the same layout with all the elements to be displayed on another page - agree there must be a better approach.

Comment: Do both pages display the same data in the same number of DataGrids? How do you display the pages, using a Frame? Do the pages contain additional content or only the Data´Grids? Where do you load/control the pages? Please provide more context so that I can help you with a small example.

Comment: Both pages should display the same data (attached pages canvas screenshot) - Pages is the master and cellsettings will have a copy with the same layout.

There is button when clicked adds a grid with a label to the Page canvas  - want this to add the same to another xaml file which also has a canvas on the design page.
The design page and code-behind is in my question - let me know if you need anything more

Comment: @BionicCode The number of rows, columns  and grids are dynamic - and user can add up to 8 grids

Comment: more code added

Comment: Thank you! It looks like you don't know data binding, do you? You still miss the context of your pages. The way you show a Page. I was trying to make sense out of your code. For example, why you are creating an instance of `CellSettingsPage ` in your `Page` class and how you are displaying it. The most "reasonable" scenario I can come up with is that were helples and didn't know how to access the `CellSettingsPage` from your `Page` class and the only solution was to create an instance of `CellSettingsPage`.

Comment: If this is true then it's obvious why modifying this instance does not yield the desired results. The `CellSettingsPage` instance that is displayed and the instance you modify are not the same instance. I hope you understand that you must modify the instance that is displayed in order to see the results. Please see this example for a simple and performant way to navigate between pages (screens) or (how to show different views dynamically): [C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792).

Comment: Regarding your code, both XAML files share the same partial class `PagesPage` as both have set `x:Class="test.Views.PagesPage"`, which doesn't make sense. It's either a copy and paste err when creating this post or another error in your code. Of course, "Cells.xaml" must set `x:Class="CellSettingsPage". Also you should know how to use data binding because you won't be able to implement a graceful solution and instead end up with overly complicated code: [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256733/discussion-between-ram-and-bioniccode).

Answer (score 0):

Please see this post for an example on how to create a single page application or how to dynamically load controls/views: [C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792).

The following example assumes that you follow the pattern of the provided link. The following example will show how you have to design the `UserControl` for a page and how they share the same `DataContext` in order to show the same data and share the same content section to share the same layout of the particular data view. The page controls are named `MainPage` and `CellSettingsPage` (I'm trying to stick to your original code as much as possible).

You need to know

- [Microsoft learn: Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0)
- [Microsoft learn: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

**PageId.cs**

```cs
enum PageId
{
  Default = 0,
  MainPage,
  CellSettingsPage
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="This is the 'MainPage'" />

    <TabControl Background="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="0">
      <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" Header="Pages">
    
        <!-- 
             This is the host for the shared view section.
             You can embed it into the page layout by placing this ContentControl
             where you want the TabControl that contains DataGrids to appear.
            
             The ContentControl.Content binds to a property on this UserControl.
             Simply define a DataTemplate e.g. in App.xaml to define the visuals.
             Because the other page will use the DataTemplate (and data model),
             both will show the exact same data view 
             (without duplicating any data as the data is shared).
        -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=SharedDataSource}" />
      </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
  public object SharedDataSource
  {
    get => (object)GetValue(SharedDataSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(SharedDataSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SharedDataSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SharedDataSource",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(MainPage),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

**CellSettingsPage.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="This is the 'CellSettingsPage'" />

    <TabControl Background="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="0">
      <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" Header="CellPages">
    
        <!-- 
             This is the host for the shared view section.
             You can embed it into the page layout by placing this ContentControl
             where you want the TabControl that contains DataGrids to appear.
            
             The ContentControl.Content binds to a property on this UserControl.
             Simply define a DataTemplate e.g. in App.xaml to define the visuals.
             Because the other page will use the DataTemplate (and data model),
             both will show the exact same data view 
             (without duplicating any data as the data is shared).
        -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=SharedDataSource}" />
      </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**CellSettingsPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class CellSettingsPage : UserControl
{
  public object SharedDataSource
  {
    get => (object)GetValue(SharedDataSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(SharedDataSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SharedDataSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SharedDataSource",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(CellSettingsPage),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public CellSettingsPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>

    <!-- The DataTemplate for the MainPageViewModel -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="MainPageViewModel">
      <MainPage SharedDataSource="{Binding SharedData}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- The DataTemplate for the CellSettingsPageViewModel -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="CellSettingsPageViewModel">
      <MainPage SharedDataSource="{Binding SharedData}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- 
         The DataTemplate for the SharedDataItem.
         This will actually show the stacked DataGrid elements.
    -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="SharedDataItem">
      <ListBox ItemsSource0"{Binding DataTables}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate DataType="DataTable">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ListBox>     
    </DataTemplate>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**SharedDataItem.cs**

```cs
// TODO::Implement INotifyPropertyChanged. 
// If there are properties that change their values 
// then let them raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event.
class SharedDataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<DataTable> DataTables { get; }

  public SharedDataItem()
    => this.DataTables = new ObservableCollection<DataTable>();
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
// TODO::Implement INotifyPropertyChanged. 
// If there are properties that change their values 
// then let them raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event.
class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Title { get; }
  public SharedDataItem ShareData { get; }

  public MainPageViewModel(string title, SharedDataItem sharedDataContext)
  {  
    this.Title = title;
    this.SharedData = sharedDataContext;
  }
}
```

**CellSettingsPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
// TODO::Implement INotifyPropertyChanged. 
// If there are properties that change their values 
// then let them raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event.
class CellSettingsPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Title { get; }
  public SharedDataItem ShareData { get; }

  public CellSettingsPageViewModel(string title, SharedDataItem sharedDataContext)
  {  
    this.Title = title;
    this.SharedData = sharedDataContext;
  }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**
The example uses the RelayCommand implementation found at [Microsoft learn: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)

```cs
// TODO::Implement INotifyPropertyChanged. 
// If there are properties that change their values 
// then let them raise the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event.
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // TODO::Raise INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event
  public string CurrentContext { get; set: }

  public ICommand SelectPageContextCommand { get; }
  private Dictionary<PageId, INotifyPropertyChanged> PageContexts { get; } 

  public MainViewModel(string title)
  {
    this.SelectPageContextCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSelectPageContextCommand, CanExecuteSelectPageContextCommand);
    var sharedDataContext = new SharedDataItem();
   
    // Add shared data to the 'sharedDataContext'.
    // TODO::Create the DataTables that will be displayed in a DataGrid each.
    // Conceptual example code:
    for (int datTableCount = 0; dataTableCount < 3; dataTableCount++)
    {
      DataTable sharedDataTable = CreateDataTable();
      sharedDataContext.DataTables.Add(sharedDataTable);
    }
   
    this.PageContexts = new Dictionary<PageId, INotifyPropertyChanged>
    {
      { PageId.MainPage, new MainPageViewModel("Main page", sharedDataContext) },
      { PageId.CellSettingsPage, new CellSettingsPageViewModel("Cell settings page", sharedDataContext) },
    };

    // Set start page
    SelectCurrentContext(PageId.MainPage);
  }
      
  private void SelectCurrentContext(PageId pageContextId)
  {
    if (this.PageContexts.TryGetValue(pageContextId, out INotifyPropertyChanged pageContext))
    {
      this.CurrentContext = pageContext;
    }
  }

  private bool CanExecuteSelectPageContextCommand(object commandParameter)
    => commandParameter is PageId pageId 
      && this.PageContexts.ContainsKey(pageId);

  private void ExecuteSelectPageContextCommand(object commandParameter)
    => SelectCurrentContext((PageId)commandParameter); 
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
  
    <!-- Page navigation -->
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Button Content="Main page" 
              Command="{Binding SelectPageContextCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{x:Static PageId.MainPage}" />
      <Button Content="Show Welcome Screen" 
              Command="{Binding SelectPageContextCommand}" 
              CommandParameter="{x:Static PageId.CellSettingsPage}" />
    </StackPanel>
  
    <!-- 
      Host of CurrentContext. 
      Automatically displays the DataTemplate (defined in App.xaml) 
      that matches the current data type (e.g. CellSettingsPageViewModel)
    -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentContext}" />
  <StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Notes: the code was written without IDE in this editor using *a lot* copy & paste. Therefore, it may contain some copy & paste related errors. Just keep that in mind when you encounter code that makes little sense like wrong variable names and typos in general etc.
However, if you satisfy the *TODO* code annotations in this example the code is supposed to compile and execute.