# How to Cancel ToggleButton Animation on Window Switch

Tags: wpf, togglebutton

I use this ToggleButton for my SettingsWindow. When i switch over to my SettingsWindow i can see the Animation of Every ToggleButton that is in the ON State. I want them to be fully enabled already without seeing the Animation of them. How can i achieve this?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Key="ToggleButton">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                                <Border x:Name="border" Cursor="Hand" CornerRadius="12.5" Width="50" Height="25">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#363031" x:Name="backgroundbrush"/>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <Border CornerRadius="12.5">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#000000" Opacity="0" x:Name="hoverbrush"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Ellipse Width="17.5" Height="17.5" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="-25,0,0,0" x:Name="ellipse"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Label FontFamily="Livvic" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,0,0">
                                <Label.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" ShadowDepth="4" Opacity="0.25"/>
                                </Label.Effect>
                            </Label>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation To="#d151ff" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundbrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"/>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation To="25,0,0,0" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation To="#363031" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundbrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"/>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation To="-25,0,0,0" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I want the Buttons i turned On before to be fully on the On State when i Switch to my Settings Window.

Comment: I think the question is how do you set the initial state of the view? You must initialize the view properly before sowing it. If you change the state after it is completely loaded then you will trigger the animations. Normally you would have a data model that you bind to the UI so that it dynamically renders the data based on a DataTemplate. This way you can initialize the data model properly and *then* assign it e.g. to a ContentControl. How to fix your problem depends on how you show your views. The animations themselves are not relevant. So you showed the wrong code.

Comment: This link shows how to navigate between views based on data models. This will give you full control about the initial state of the view. It also simplifies the overall handling significantly. [C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323201/3141792)

Answer (score 0):

The animation is playing whenever the `ToggleButton`'s `IsChecked` property is set to `true` - even if that's the initial visible state - because the `Trigger` can't distinguish between an initial state of `true` and a transition from `false` to `true`. Or more specifically from the built-in [control states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/togglebutton-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) of `Unchecked` to `Checked`.

Instead you can use `VisualStateManager` and `VisualState`'s to get the right behavior:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition From="Unchecked"
                                      To="Checked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundbrush"
                                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                          Duration="00:00:00.2">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame Value="#d151ff" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
                                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                              Duration="00:00:00.2">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame Value="25,0,0,0"/>
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition>
                    <VisualTransition From="Checked"
                                      To="Unchecked">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundbrush"
                                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                                          Duration="00:00:00.2">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame Value="#363031" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
                                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                              Duration="00:00:00.2">
                                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame Value="-25,0,0,0"/>
                            </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backgroundbrush"
                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame Value="#d151ff" 
                                                 KeyTime="0"/>
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse"
                                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame Value="25,0,0,0"
                                                     KeyTime="0"/>
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <Border x:Name="border"
                    Cursor="Hand"
                    CornerRadius="12.5"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="25">
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#363031"
                                     x:Name="backgroundbrush" />
                </Border.Background>
                <Border CornerRadius="12.5">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#000000"
                                         Opacity="0"
                                         x:Name="hoverbrush" />
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Ellipse Width="17.5"
                             Height="17.5"
                             Fill="#ffffff"
                             Margin="-25,0,0,0"
                             x:Name="ellipse" />
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <Label FontFamily="Livvic"
               Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
               Foreground="White"
               FontSize="20"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Grid.Column="1"
               Margin="5,0,0,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Padding="0,0,0,0">
            <Label.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4"
                                  ShadowDepth="4"
                                  Opacity="0.25" />
            </Label.Effect>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Again these states are built into the Control's internal/private backing code (invoked via [VisualStateManager.GoToState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate?view=winrt-22621)). Any time you're re-templating a Control, you should always look up the default states and template [on the WPF documentation site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) so you can respond to these states as you want.

Unfortunately it is a lot of XAML and there is some duplication - you need to fully specify the static/initial state for `Checked` as well as the end states for both transition animations. I'm not aware of any way around this but if I'm wrong I'm sure someone will correct me. On the flip side you don't need anything special for the `Unchecked` state because that matches the normal state of the control as you've templated it.