# Calling CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested in ViewModelBase?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, relaycommand

**Initial problem:**
I'm using the typical `RelayCommand` implementation in my MVVM Application.
I realized that the `CanExecute` of my `RelayCommand` is not always called even if meaningful properties of my ViewModel have changed.

I read that we can manually call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested` to raise a `RequerySuggested` event. This will eventually make the Command Source call the `CanExecute` method.

`RequerySuggested` is automatically raised by the `CommandManager` when some UI events occurs. I feel like it would be useful if it would also be raised on `PropertyChanged`.

**My current solution:**
I modified the property changed method of my `ViewModelBase` class like this:

```cs
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    Application.Current.Dispatcher?.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested);
}
```

**Concerns:**
I have not found any `ViewModelBase` online implemented this way and I feel like this should be a red flag.

`RelayCommand` is highly recommended in MVVM for it's simplicity so I find weird that I end up having to manually call the CommandManager. Why not preferring `DelegateCommand` then?

I know that this causes the `CanExecute` to be called more often, but it is already spammed every time a UI event happens anyway.

Comment: Usually implementations of ICommand have some method of raising the CanExecuteChanged event. Have you tried that? IMO much cleaner and more efficient than CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested

Comment: Look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand) how implementation is done

Comment: To trigger the  `RequerySuggested` from the `PropertyChanged`  event invocator of your base view model is a bad idea. It will trigger the `RequerySuggested` event when _any_ property has changed. No matter if the property is part of a command logic or not. This creates a huge overhead given that the `ViewModelBase` is used throughout the whole application and extended by a many classes. Usually the `CanExecute` is called on focus changes or keyboard and mouse events. This is sufficient most of the time. For special situations you can explicitly call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`

Comment: @DaveM 
You mean having a public `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`? The one from Josh Smith does not. I agree that it could be cleaner.  
@BionicCode  

That's where I'm confused I guess. I feel like having to _sometimes_ manually call the command manager defeats the purpose of `RelayCommand`. I'll try thinking of a better long term solution for when the CanExecute could change without any user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"typical" relaycommand?

If you're using MVVMLight's relaycommand then the source is:

https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommand.cs

You can call CanExecutechanged on the relaycomand.

When you add the using statement to any viewmodel, make sure you use the CommandWPF version.

InvalidateRequerySuggested is called when there is a user input event. You would therefore be raising it twice when a user inputs anything and that changes a property you raise propertychanged on. Meaning your approach is a bad idea.

It's rare to have some data comes from a model to a viewmodel on a property by property basis. Much more usual that an event is raised and the viewmodel then composes data from a viewmodel into properties. You could probably just raise canexecutechanged the once after you get a new record or a change event or however your data changes happen when they're not user input driven.

Comment: Thank you. I used Josh Smith's RelayCommand which does not contain a way of raising the CanExecuteChanged manually. I'll modify my version and just raise the event when I need it.