# WPF: How to implement Clear command

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm learning WPF.

In one of the exercises, I have a TextBox and buttons Cut and Paste. The following is enough to implement Cut and Paste functionality:

**XAML:**

```
<DockPanel>
    <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="3">
        <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtEditor}"
                Width="60">
                _Cut
        </Button>
        <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtEditor}"
                Width="60" Margin="3,0">
                _Paste<
        /Button>
    </WrapPanel>
    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtEditor" />
    </DockPanel>
```

When pressed, the button Cut executes the `ApplicationCommands.Cut` on the TextBox with name `txtEditor`. When needed, the button will ask the TextBox with name textEditor if it can execute a Cut command, and when pressed it will order the textEditor to execute the Cut command.

Fairly straightforward. It works fine.

Just for Fun, I'd like to  implement another button: Clear. When pressed it should clear the TextBox. The Textbox class has a method Clear.

```
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Clear"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtEditor}"
                Width="60">
                Clear
        </Button>
```

Alas, this won't work. `ApplicationCommands` doesn't have a `Clear`. Should I implement a custom command, as suggested in [this example](https://wpf-tutorial.com/commands/implementing-custom-commands/)?

**I tried the following:**

I implemented CanExecute and Executed methods in my window:

```
public partial class CustomCommandSample : Window
{
    public CustomCommandSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ClearCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void ClearCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtEditor.Clear();
    }
}
```

A static CustomCommands class:

```
public static class CustomCommands
{
    public static RoutedUICommand Clear => new RoutedUICommand (
        "Clear",
        "Clear",
        typeof(CustomCommands));
}
```

Finally the XAML:
(Note: the classes in this project are in namespace WpfCommandDemo. Xaml refers to it as `Local`)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Commands.UsingCommandsSample"
    xmlns="...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCommandDemo"
    Title="UsingCommandsSample" Height="100" Width="200">

    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="CustomCommands.Clear"
                        CanExecute="ClearCommand_CanExecute"
                        Executed="ClearCommand_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>

 <DockPanel>
    <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="3">
        <Button Command="CustomCommands.Clear"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=txtEditor}"
                Width="60">
                Clear
        </Button>
        ... (other buttons: cut / paste, as above
    </WrapPanel>
        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtEditor" />
    </DockPanel>
```

Although this compiles, The constructor of CustomCommandSample throws an XamlParseException:

```
Type reference cannot find type named 
'{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}CustomCommands'.
```

Should I solve the problem using Custom Commands? What should I change? Or am I completely wrong, and should I solve this differently

Comment: You can implement your own relay command for that, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I solve the problem using Custom Commands?

Yes. This is how to solve this using the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern which is *the* recommended design pattern to use when developing XAML based UI applications.

From [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) blog post:

> WPF provides two implementations of the `ICommand` interface; the `System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand` and `System.Windows.Input.RoutedUICommand` where the latter is a subclass of the former that simply adds a `Text` property that describes the command. However, neither of these implementations are especially suited to be used in a view model as they search the visual tree from the focused element and up for an element that has a matching `System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding` object in its `CommandBindings` collection and then executes the `Execute` delegate for this particular `CommandBinding`. Since the command logic should reside in the view model, you don’t want to setup a `CommandBinding` in the view in order to connect the command to a visual element. Instead, you can create your own command by creating a class that implements the `ICommand`. The below implementation is a common one that invokes delegates for the `Execute` and `CanExecute` methods:

```
public class DelegateCommand: System.Windows.Input.ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null) { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged() => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Once you have an implementation of the `ICommand` interface, it's easy to use in your view models:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        ClearCommand = new DelegateCommand(Clear);
    }

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public ICommand ClearCommand { get; }

    private void Clear(object parameter)
    {
        Text = string.Empty;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

In the view, you simply bind to the properties of the view model:

```
<TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtEditor" Text="{Binding Text}" />
<Button Content="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" />
```

Just remember to set the `DataContext` of the view to an instance of your view model for the bindings to work:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use CustomCommands in XAML, you'll need to add a reference to it. In the  element, add a line:

```
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyApplication.NamespaceWithCustomInIt"
```

Replacing the namespace value as appropriate. Then you should be able to reference CustomCommands anywhere in XAML as `custom:CustomCommands` (may have to bind, I'll check later).