# WPF MVVM showing label text for a short time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `Label` in a statusbar in my view with which I show messages to the user. I want to show the message and change background color only for a few seconds, so that I wouldn't have to clear the label with extra lines of code.

I have a `StatusText` and `StatusColor` properties in the viewmodel, and the label content and color are bound to these, and are working fine.

My question is how do I time it in ViewModel?

Can I use a timer in the viewmodel method and in a way that doesn't freeze the UI while displaying the message?

I'm trying to adher to the MVVM framework, but I couldn't find any solutions on SO without using events. Is it possible in some simple fashion?

Comment: You could for example use a `Timer` in your view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Command instead of event. Command will find a ICommand property with matched name in ViewModel. That will decouple your View and Code-behind.

In xaml

```
<Button Command="ChangeColorCommand" />
```

In ViewModel 
Note: 
  `timer` is `System.Timers.Timer`. I skipped its instantiated code.

`TimerTicked` is called when `timer` Elapsed.

You don't have to use `DispatcherTimer` because `StatusText` and `StatusColor` are not UI object.

```
    public ICommand ChangeColorCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand( ChangeColorAndMessage );
        }
    }
    // This is your view model constructor
    private void ViewModelCtor(){
       // your initialize code here

        //subscribe event once
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval=1000;
        timer.AutoReset=false;
        timer.Elapsed += TimerTicked;
    }

    public void ChangeColorAndMessage( string[] args )
    {
        StatusText = "Button pressed";
        StatusColor = changedColor;

        // You implementation for changing it back.
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void TimerTicked( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        StatusText = "origin";
        StatusColor = originColor;

        // Fire property changed to notify view updating data.
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( StatusText ) );
        PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( StatusColor ) );
    }
```

For implementation of RelayCommand, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22285866/why-relaycommand/22286816#22286816)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do have RelayCommand implemented, and all my buttons are bound to relaycommands. The StatusText is changed in the method tied to a relaycommand, just as in your example. But the question is, how do I time it there? Can I use a timer in the viewmodel method and in a way that doesn't freeze the UI while displaying the message?

Comment: See my edit. You don't have to use `DispatcherTimer` since you don't modify UI directly. Also using timer will not freeze UI.

Comment: I had to add the bit `timer.Elapsed += TimerTicked;` in order for it to work. Added the code in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just posting my solution here, thanks for Louis Go for help.

So, I added the the timer in the VM constructor and the following methods in the viewmodel for changing the `StatusText`and `StatusColor` properties and to change them back. The properties themselves handle the change notification.

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;
private VMConstructor()
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);
    timer.AutoReset = false;
    timer.Elapsed += TimerTicked;
}

private void ChangeStatus(string text, string color)
{
    timer.Enabled = true;
    StatusText = text;
    StatusColor = color;
}

private void TimerTicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StatusColor = "Grey";
    StatusText = "";
}
```

Comment: Don't subscribe it in `ChangeStatus`, it will keep subscribing event. In the end, once Elapsed fired, you will see mutiple `TimerTicked` executed.

Comment: It is better now.